# Match names in two databases that have similar but not precisely matched rows of data

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried difflib and fuzzy wuzzy to match the names in this problem, however the match rates are poor due to variation in the names. I'm now attempting to use the additional datafields I have for the names, but am entirely unsure how to proceed with an issue like this. If I've been unclear at all please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

I have two dataframes, that hold similar, but not precisely matching information about people. I'm looking to match the reference numbers from each dataframe to the other dataframe, thes Ref numbers being unique by person. By example, in the table below, I want to know that Jimmy / James Random's (for they are the same person, but not of matching name) reference number in the first dataframe is 1234 in DF1 and 89 in DF2. Note that a person's Rank may change, but will change in both tables at the same time. Their Ref number, style, ID, and nationality will always remain the same for each person.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Ref","Date","Name", "Rank","Nationality","Style","ID"], \
                      data=[["1234","20200104","Jimmy Random","General","France","Aggressive",""],\
                           ["1333","20200104","Ian Fleming","Brigadier","England","Passive","14"],\
                           ["1234","20191204","Jimmy Random","Major","France","","15"],\
                           ["1000","20200404","Peter Nisbett","Corporal","","Passive","12"]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Ref","Date","Name", "Rank","Nationality","Style","ID"], \
                      data=[["89","20200104","James Random","","France","Aggressive","104"],\
                           ["10","20200104","I. Fleming","Brigadier","England","","4"],\
                           ["156","20200404","P. Nisbett","","Spain","Passive","5"],\
                           ["89","20191204","James Random","Major","France","Aggressive","104"]])
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance for any help given.

Cheeseburger

Comment: Please provide your sample data in the text of your question, not as a picture or link, to make a [mcve]

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text. Python can't read image to run code.

Comment: Roger that, adding code in text form

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to compare string with some additional analysis, right? Check cosine similarity, its implemented in scit-learn.

Comment: I'll go have a look at this now, thanks for the tip!!